# Want only date from epoch

Tags: java

Given millis since epoch, I want an instance with the fields Month, Date, Year filled out, with the hour minute seconds set to some default values.

What is an efficient way to do this?

I know that there are sql ways to do it but is there a way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
new Calendar(new Date(msSinceEpoch));
```

where the ms is a long value.

Comment: You can use the Calendar.get() methods to get the individual values for month/day etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use either [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#LocalDate%28long%29) or [DateMidnight](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html#DateMidnight%28long%29) in the Joda-Time API. The differences are explained in the [javadocs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html).

Note that in order to truncate a point in time (some millis since epoch) to a specific calendar day, you might want to specify when midnight happened, or else you'll end up with midnight in the system's timezone. For example, you might call the LocalDate(long, DateTimeZone) constructor instead of the LocalDate(long) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you'd rather not have a JODA dependency, use DateFormat:

```
Date thisDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd").parse("2011-Jun-29");
```

Per the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), you can easily create a Date from a long:

```
long value = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date thisDate = new Date(value);
```

Comment: i rather not use date since its deprecated. is there some other class?

Comment: Date is not deprecated.  Where did you see that?  Some of its methods are, but it's not going anywhere.  What do you think JODA and DateUtil are using?

Comment: that's what I meant...anyway I actually need long -> date

Comment: @SuperString: Date is not deprecated, only it's methods for manipulating the date fields; the alternative to the deprecated methods is a Calendar object initialized from a Date instance.